# How to place multiple icons for Google map markers in v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to create a map similar to [this](http://www.foodspotting.com/explore#/loc/Anywhere/) (which is using v2 of the API). I want each marker on the map to consist of an image with a frame or background behind [like so](http://www.foodspotting.com/images/map-shadow.png).

Using the `icon` and `shadow` MarkerOptions doesn't seem to accomplish this because a markers shadow falls behind other markers icons.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use an excellent little library, [RichMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/). Its documentation is [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/docs/reference.html).

To make usage easier, you can even create your own custom marker class, something like this:

```
Ns.Marker = function(properties) {

    RichMarker.call(this, properties);

    this.setContent('<div class="three-images-marker">' +
            properties.NsImage ? '<div class="marker-image-1"><img src="'+properties.NsImage1+'"/></div>' : '' + 
            properties.NsFrameImage ? '<div class="marker-image-2"><img src="'+properties.NsImage2+'"/></div>' : '' +
        '</div>');
};

Ns.Marker.prototype = Object.create(RichMarker.prototype);


// and use it like this:
var yourFramedMarker = new Ns.Marker({
      position: yourMarkerLatlng,
      map: yourMap,
      NsImage: 'example.com/image.png',
      NsFrameImage: 'example.com/frame.png',
});
```

'Ns' is whatever namespace you use, if you do.

From here on it's CSS work, you can position the images as you like.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to merge the images with the marker backgrounds. When I was building something similar I used CSS sprites and calculated the vertical offset (vPos), based on a standard height. I just didn't bother with the shadows.

```
     var mImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("YOURMARKER.png", 
        new google.maps.Size(34, 35), 
        new google.maps.Point(0, vPos),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34)
    ); 
    //insert marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: mImage,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        map: map
    });
```

Comment: So, you targeted the MarkerImages via CSS and set the background on those? What did that selector look like?

Comment: .mapMarker { height:35px;width:34px;background-position: 0 0}

Answer (score 0):

yes, marker shadows are all placed in the separate layer - below all markers. You have to merge the background and photo into one icon image, or [create a new class which would inherit from MarkerImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8328154/684229).