# How can I show a custom DIV element on a google map as a marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to be able to show a custom DIV element on a Google Map (V3 API) as a marker but it only seems to allow images to be used instead. Is there any way around this using the standard google map API?

Comment: nice question. You could use other overlay type instead of marker for this, but then you can't use other marker functionality (e.g. dragging, events, etc.). So your requirement is absolutely legitimate and interesting! PS: maybe it could help to make your own descendant of class MarkerImage and pass it as icon using `setIcon`!

Comment: yes, that's a good point. I did think of rendering the DIV as an image on the server and then doing using the image for the marker, as you said. Just looking for a simpler solution (if possible) first

Comment: nope, i did not mean to render something on the server,that would be really clumsy. Just try to define a descendant of MarkerImage class which supports DIVs.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excellent little library: [RichMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/). Its documentation is [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/docs/reference.html).

You can use the `content` property of the json object passed to the constructor like this:

```
var marker = new RichMarker({
      position: yourLatLng,
      map: yourMap,
      content: '<div class="my-flexible-marker">initial content</div>'
});
```

And later change the content with the `setContent` method:

```
marker.setContent('<div class="my-flexible-marker">new content</div>');
```